# How to do the following string comparison and conditionals efficiently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, if-statement

I have 3 inputs to take from the user and each input has 3 different options to choose from..

```
first, second, third = input("Enter the values (full/half/nothing: ").split()
in first:      #not sure about this syntax
    if first == "half":
        #call first.half function
    elif first == "full":
        #call first.full function
    else:
        #call nothing function
in second:
    if second == "half":
        #call second.half function
    elif second == "full":
        #call second.full function
    else:
        #call nothing function
in third:
    if third == "half":
        #call third.half function
    elif third == "full":
        #call third.full function
    else:
        #call nothing function
```

So with each input it should call a different function.I'm kind of new to python, not sure how to handle the conditional statements efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

"in first" does not seem to be valid syntax. The best thing to do (imho) would be to store the items in a list, and then iterate through each item. And `.split()` should be `.split('/')` if you want the input to be `half/full/half`, etc.

Assuming all of your functions are defined, you can store them in a list:

```
functions = [
    [first_half, first_full], 
    [second_half, second_full], 
    [third_half, third_full],
    nothing
]
```

Then, you can store the output to a list and iterate over it:

```
first, second, third = input("Enter the values (full/half/nothing: ").split("/")
items = [first, second, third]
for index, item in enumerate(items):
    # index is the position of 'item', begining at 0
    # item is the actual response, i.e. the first, second, and then third variable

    if item == "half":
        functions[index][0]()
    elif item == "full":
        functions[index][1]()
    else:
        functions[3]()
```

For reference, the full script, including the dummy functions:

```
def nothing():
    print("nothing")

def first_half():
    print("first_half")

def first_full():
    print("first_full")

def second_half():
    print("second_half")

def second_full():
    print("second_full")

def third_half():
    print("third_half")

def third_full():
    print("third_full")

functions = [
    [first_half, first_full], 
    [second_half, second_full], 
    [third_half, third_full],
    nothing
]

first, second, third = input("Enter the values (full/half/nothing: ").split("/")
items = [first, second, third]
for index, item in enumerate(items):
    # index is the position of 'item', begining at 0
    # item is the actual response, i.e. the first, second, and then third variable

    if item == "half":
        functions[index][0]()
    elif item == "full":
        functions[index][1]()
    else:
        functions[3]()
```